# Determining whether a phrase is a named entity in a document in a Java program

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm new to Stanford NLP and I'm trying to use it in my Java application for the following problem.
I have a Wikipedia article (say, the one with title "Washington, D.C.") and I would like to determine whether the phrase forming the title (in my case, "Washington, D.C.") refers to a named entity, by analyzing the text of the article.

Following the example that I found in the file Demo.java, included in the Stanford NLP distribution, I declared the following classifier:

```
AbstractSequenceClassifier<CoreLabel> classifier = CRFClassifier.getClassifier("src/main/resources/org/graphipedia/ner/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz");
```

Then I called the method classify on this classifier:

```
List<List<CoreLabel>> resClassifier = classifier.classify(text)
```

where the argument is the text of the Wikipedia page. 
The problem now is that when I iterate over the result of the classifier, each element of the list is single word (annotated with a class). 
Therefore the three tokens forming my title "Washington", "," and "D.C." are treated separately, and (possibly) annotated differently.
Thus, I can determine whether any part of my title is a named entity, but I cannot do the same on the whole title.

I read on Stanford NLP website that something similar can be achieved with RegexNER, which would allow to consider group of words as a single entity.
But I'm not sure how to use it with AbstractSequenceClassifier. Also, it seems that with RegexNER I have to specify the tokens that I want to be considered as a single entity (in my case, the phrase "Washington, D.C.") in a file, which is not something that I want. 
Ideally, I would like to repeat this classification task for many Wikipedia articles, and I don't really want to create a file for each article.

Could you give me some hints on how I could tackle this seemingly easy problem to solve?

Thanks in advance.

Gianluca

Answer (score 0):

Stanford CoreNLP provides a `mentions` annotator which will group adjacent words with the same NER tag into a single mention. However, in your case, it is almost certainly easier to just do so yourself. If the majority of words in the title have an NER tag associated with them, then likely the title is a named entity.

Tangential, but I would also recommend using either the `StanfordCoreNLP` object to annotate NER tags (`new StanfordCoreNLP(props).annotate(annotation)`), or the simple CoreNLP API included in the latest release: `List<String> tags = new Sentence("your headline").nerTags();`.